# Filter remote results with pagination

Tags: web-services, rest, filter, pagination

I have a REST API which supports pagination and filtering, like

```
GET /jobs?page=1&count=10&language=php&country=!UK
Host: mywebservice.com
```

where 1 is the number of the page and count is the number of results per page.

The problem is, I get the 'jobs' from another web service which also give me the results paginated (I cannot get all the jobs) but does not support filters like 'country=!UK' (country not UK).
I will call:

```
GET /opportunities?page=1&count=10&language=php
Host: jobs.com
```

After I get the jobs from this service, I need to apply another filter (not supported by this 3rd party web service - eg: remove all the jobs from a specific company or a specific country).

In this case the results set which I will send back to the user can be less than 10 jobs (0 to 10).

Which would be the best practice to get the optimal number of results per page (10, the number requested by the user) with the minimum number of calls to the 3rd party service?

Answer (score 1):

you have two options:

1) **be greed**: request the 3d party service for more items.

2) **be lazy**: accept the *possibility* of issuing a second (or third) call to the 3d party service

these options fulfill **network optimization** and **payload optimization** respectively. The best solution depends on the probability of obtaining a satisfying response at the first call, by requesting few more items. It's a "value for money" problem. Try to identify the most favorable probability of obtaining your 10 items, by minimizing the amount of paged items requested to the 3d party service.

A good idea would also be to use a combined approach by performing a greedy strategy and using a second request as a fallback solution. If you reckon the prebability well, you'll pursue an optimal solution by minimizing the number of request and the payload weight.